# How do I indicate where Emscripten should locate source files during compile?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, emscripten, webassembly

Being a Javascript programmer, I'm really not quite familiar with the compiling process. My problem is locating source files during compilation with Emscripten. My "include"-commands refer to source code, such as "Core/main.h", which in turn refers to other source files in the same folder, yet using a similar address, (e.g. "Core/app.h")

How do I overcome these "File not found" errors? How do I indicate to the Emscripten compiler that it should look in the source folder? I've been reading the documentation, but what I'm finding discusses, I think, virtual file systems for use during run time, not included directories during compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the one argument that is the same on virtually every C/C++ compiler: -I

```
emcc -Idir1 -Idir2 ... foo.c
```

Where the file is at dir1/Core/app.h.